# Can I make one command with "find . -name ".sv" | xargs grep -n "word for finding" "

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, find

I'm trying to make an alias or something like command with grep and find command in linux.

kinda    `"find . -name ".sv" | xargs grep -n "word for finding" "`

Can I make one command or aliasing with `find` `xargs` `grep` ?

so I want to use like this with those 3 commands.

If I type like this:

```
%fxgrep love
```

then find `love` word within sub-directory in *.sv files.

Comment: Useful link, so you know some key words to advance your own research: [In Bash, when to alias, when to script, and when to write a function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30925/108618)

Comment: Using `xargs` gets complicated if you want to support files with spaces in the name and such, your command can also be written: `find . -name ".sv" -exec grep -n "word for finding" {} \;` (but given its form it should be a function, not an alias).

Comment: @xenoid Would you please any example how can we make a util?

Answer (score 1):

The 'alias' command is what you're looking for

```
alias aliasname='commands'
```

Comment: But in your case, we can't set the argument what we are trying for watching it. Every single time, that argument what we are looking for some word is changing. how do we apply this way ?

Comment: It's possible to pass arguments to an alias command, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941338/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-shell-alias

Answer (score 1):

Using xargs gets complicated if you want to support files with spaces in the name and such, your command can also be written: `find . -name ".sv" -exec grep -n "word for finding" {} \;` but given its form it should be a function:

```
function fxgrep { find . -name ".sv" -exec grep -n "$1" {} \; ; }
```

Invoke with quoted argument if there are spaces:

```
fxgrep "several words"
```

Comment: Great! But can I use it at cshell? How do I implement it to cshell?

Comment: You [cannot define functions in (t)csh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13916515/function-instead-of-alias-in-c-shell-login-script).  But why are you using this antiquity?